# SimpleInjector does not inject property using Implicit Property Injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have an `ObjectA`, which has a property for `ObjectB`, which has a property for `ObjectC`, which are all in the [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) container.  When I create `ObjectA`, I call `InjectProperties` on it, which loads up `ObjectB`. However, at this time, it does not load up the reference to `ObjectC` within the newly created `ObjectB`; it does not perform what I'll call a "deep buildup" of objects.

Is there a way to enable this?

**EDIT**

I have a class object A:

```
public class ObjectA
{
     public ObjectB InstanceB { get; set; }
}
```

Which has a property to `ObjectB`:

```
public class ObjectB
{
     public ObjectC InstanceC { get; set; }
}
```

All have been registered using the standard register method on the container.  To get `ObjectA`, I use `GetInstance<ObjectA>(),` and this comes back fine,  I also built an initializer to build up all objects upon creation:

```
_container.RegisterInitializer<object>(i => _container.InjectProperties(i));
```

This injects `ObjectB` into `ObjectA`, but does not then inject `ObjectC` into `ObjectB`, at the time it resolves `ObjectB`.

Is there a workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: the Simple Injector system should build your entire tree out of the box, can you post sample code, including container registrations.
you might want to consider using constructor injection instead of explicitly injecting properties after construction.  if you cannot change this pattern you might want to consider a different IoC container, like Unity.  This definitely supports post construction deep build-ups

Comment: Please show the code of those classes and the registration. I agree with most Robert said, except about switching to Unity (especially Unity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little test using your code and your configuration (and added the missing `ObjectC`):

```cs
public class ObjectA
{
    public ObjectB InstanceB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public ObjectC InstanceC { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectC
{

}
```

The test:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void ImplicitPropertyInjectionTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var container = new Container();

    container.RegisterInitializer<object>(
        i => container.InjectProperties(i));

    // Act
    var a = container.GetInstance<ObjectA>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(a.InstanceB);
    Assert.IsNotNull(a.InstanceB.InstanceC);
}
```

The test succeeds and `InstanceC` is correctly injected. I expect there to be something wrong with your configuration or perhaps `ClassC` can not be created. Try requesting `ClassC` directly to find out why the container can not create it:

```
container.GetInstance<ClassC>();
```

This line will probably fail and that's the reason that `InstanceC` is not injected.

This directly brings me at the following:

Calling `RegisterInitializer<object>(instance => container.InjectProperties(instance))` like you did, is an effective way to enable implicit property injection, but you should avoid using implicit property injection as much as possible, since this leads to a container configuration that can not be verified (by using `container.Verify()` for instance). You already noticed this, because `InstanceC` was skipped over. Instead you should use constructor injection as much as possible. See more information about writing your code in a way that it can be verified [here](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to&referringTitle=Documentation#Verifying_Configuration).

If it is impossible to use constructor injection in certain scenarios, prefer using explicit property injection, which is done as follows:

```
container.RegisterInitializer<ClassA>(a =>
{
    a.InstanceB = container.GetInstance<ClassB>();
});

container.RegisterInitializer<ClassB>(b =>
{
    b.InstanceC = container.GetInstance<ClassC>();
});
```

This explicitly injects properties `InstanceB` and `InstanceC`, and will fail construction when the properties can not be injected.

More about doing property injection with Simple Injector can be found [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios&#Property-Injection).

Last note. Please note that all containers behave about the same when it comes to implicit property injection. So this is not specific to the Simple Injector. If this feature is supported by that container, it will skip every property that can't be injected. In other words, all containers will fail silently and continue, which is typically not what you want. This means that you have to be extra careful when working with a container that enables implicit property injection by default.